# New process in Windows API

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I work with WinAPI and I have a function that creates a new process:

```
void new_process() {
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    TCHAR szCommandLine[] = TEXT("NOTEPAD");
    CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```

But when I call this function from `main()`, it's doesn't work:

```
void new_process(TCHAR szCommandLine[]) {
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    CreateProcess(NULL, szCommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    new_process(TEXT("NOTEPAD"));
    return 0;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: "Where is my mistake?" not checking for errors.

Comment: Please don't use `TCHAR`, it's 2015, not 1998.

Comment: Use `GetLastError` function to check what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx). MSDN says -

> The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the
>   contents of this string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer
>   to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If
>   this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access
>   violation.

When you pass TEXT("NOTEPAD") as the parameter to the function new_process(TCHAR szCommandLine[]) which in turn passes this as the lpCommandLine parameter to the CreateProcess() API, it will try to modify this location as quoted from MSDN above.

Since the parameter TEXT("NOTEPAD") is a CONSTANT memory, when the CreateProcess() tries to modify this memory as quoted above, it will cause memory access violation.

So ideally you should call the function new_process(TCHAR szCommandLine[]) from the main() function as given below.

```
TCHAR APP_NAME[] = TEXT("NOTEPAD");   
new_process(APP_NAME);
```

Hope this help!